# How to remove disabled attribute from button?

Tags: c#, asp.net

How to remove disabled attribute from asp.net button from code-behind.

I have made disbled attribute to be true for button from javascript and want to enable it in code-behind.

In Javascript,

```
btnCalc.disabled=true;
```

In Code-behind,in the checkbox changed event,I am making it to enable,

```
btnCalc.enabled=true;//but this does not enable the button.
```

I tried to remove attributed for button,but it didt works for me.

```
btnCalc.Attributes.Remove("disabled");
```

Please,let me know,any other way to achieve this.

Comment: Whatever you are doing there - there's probably an error in the programming sequence. So your .enabled = true probably runs before disabled = true

Comment: @Grumbler: First disabled happens n then enabling as per my logic.

Comment: Did you verify that with an JS-Debugger?
You are doing js in your code behind, right?

Comment: I verfied from javascipt.I am not using JS in code-behid.

Comment: But this here `btnCalc.enabled` is no valid C# code?
And you have to check the lifecycle as SelaYou is saying... You could just omit the JS and use code-behind only.

Comment: What are you trying to do in `code-behind`? is it on javascript or C#?

Comment: @MahaSwetha +1 :) got working...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi Maha  i have Tried this and Got Working.,

**JavaScript:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        function handleChange(cb) {
        var btn = document.getElementById('ButtonTest');
        if (cb.checked == true) {
            btn.disabled = true;
            alert('Checked True');
            return true;
        } else {
            alert('False');
            btn.disabled = false;
            return false;
        }
    }
    </script>
```

**ASPX Page Code:**

```
<div>
    <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="checkMe" title="Hey Check Me" name="Check Me" ClientIDMode="Static" onclick="handleChange(this)" AutoPostBack="false" Text="Check Me" />

    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="ButtonTest" title="Hey Check Me" ClientIDMode="Static" Text="Submit Button" OnClick="ButtonTest_Click" />
</div>
```

**Code Behind:**

```
protected void ButtonTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Your Logic
}
```

But the Check Box `AutoPostBack="false"` should be in false. Other wise the Entire page will be reloaded and disabled will attribute will removed.

Hope it may helpful., :)

Answer (score 0):

You may need some knowledge of ASP.NET page life circle
You enabled the button from code-behind, it just help generate a response text to browser, the JavaScript will run after browser load HTML(the response text), you JavaScript code run and disable the button again.

You can register a startup script to enable the button after you disable button script